# JSON Escaping double quotes not working

Tags: javascript, java, json

I'm getting errors on a screen when it's trying to eval some json, it's giving me the error unexpected identifier..

The data causing the issue and how it's coming back when I check the Json response is:

"itemDescription":"STANDARD \"B\" RED BOX",

I'm using the below code in the java to handle the double quotes:

```
itemDescription = itemDescription.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");
itemDescription = itemDescription.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");
itemDescription = itemDescription.replaceAll("'", "&apos;");
```

Any idea why this wouldn't be working? If I remove the double quotes, I no longer get any errors.

Item descriptions such as "itemDescription":"STANDARD 16\" RED BOX" go through fine..

Thanks!

Comment: What are you using to eval the Json? Are you using `eval()`? Or `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: It's only escaping the first double quote for some reason, looking at the error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two more backslashes at line 2:

```
itemDescription = itemDescription.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\\\"").
```

So that  `"` is replaced by `\\\"` and not `\\"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [StringEscapeUtils](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.0) :

```
itemDescription  = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(itemDescription);
```